# Efficiently query product variants from inventory database (avoiding EAV)

Tags: mysql, join, query, many-to-many

I'm building an ecommerce website for fun with three main components: frontend in Angular, MySQL database and a PHP backend that will function as a REST API.

The inventory database consists of products of which there are many variants (Yes, I've seen many questions on StackExchange discussing these kind of issues but I havent found a satisfying soultion yet). After reading several horror stories of using an EAV approach, Im avoiding that.

I think I have made a database solution that works, but Im uncertain to how I should query the data. As there are several many-to-many relationships a query for 1 product and all its variants can return several rows where only a couple columns contain "new" data.

**(TL:DR) Main question: When querying a product for all its variants (colors, sizes of available colors and quantity of a color/size variant), what is most efficient:**

- Perform 1 database query returning many rows where I would need to build an associative array in PHP, discarding "duplicate" data?
- Perform several queries when retrieving all variants of  a product?
- Or is there a flaw in the database design which is the cause of these issues?

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `productID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `longDescription` TEXT,
  `shortDescription` VARCHAR(1000),
  PRIMARY KEY (`productID`)
);
INSERT INTO `products` (`productID`, `name`, `longDescription`, `shortDescription`) VALUES 
(1, 'A shirt', 'Long description of this product', 'shortDesc of shirt');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productpricing` (
  `productID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1971-01-01 00:00:00',
  `endDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '2099-01-01 00:00:00',
  `price` DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`productID`, `endDate`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`productID`) REFERENCES products(`productID`) 
);
INSERT INTO `productpricing` (`productID`, `startDate`, `endDate`, `price`) VALUES
(1, '1971-01-01 00:00:00', '2099-01-01 00:00:00', 309.99);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `categoryID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoryName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryID`)
);
INSERT INTO `categories` (`categoryID`, `categoryName`) VALUES
(1, 'Test Category');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sizes` (
  `sizeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `size` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sizeID`)
);
INSERT INTO `sizes` (`sizeID`, `size`) VALUES
(1, 50),
(2, 56),
(3, 62),
(4, 68),
(5, 74),
(6, 80),
(7, 86);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colors` (
  `colorID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `color` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`colorID`)
);
INSERT INTO `colors` (`colorID`, `color`) VALUES
(1, "Red"),
(2, "White"),
(3, "Blue"),
(4, "Purple");

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_variants` (
  `productvariantID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `productID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoryID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `colorID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `sizeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `sku` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productvariantID`),
  UNIQUE (`productID`, `colorID`, `sizeID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`productID`) REFERENCES products(`productID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) REFERENCES categories(`categoryID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`colorID`) REFERENCES colors(`colorID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`sizeID`) REFERENCES sizes(`sizeID`)
);
INSERT INTO `product_variants` (`productvariantID`, `productID`, `categoryID`, `colorID`, `sizeID`, `sku`, `quantity`, `isActive`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 'clalb121', 2, 1),
(2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 'clalb132', 1, 1),
(3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 'clalb122', 5, 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `imageID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imageFilename` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`imageID`)
);
INSERT INTO `images` (`imageID`, `imageFilename`) VALUES
(1, 'shirtwhite1.jpg'),
(2, 'shirtwhite2.jpg'),
(3, 'shirtblue1.jpg'),
(4, 'shirtblue2.jpg');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_variant_images` (
  `productvariantID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `imageID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(`productvariantID`) REFERENCES  product_variants(`productvariantID`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`imageID`) REFERENCES images(`imageID`)
);
INSERT INTO `product_variant_images` (`productvariantID`, `imageID`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(3, 1),
(3, 2);
```

(Im going to remove *categoryID* from the *product_variants* table as different variants of the same product does not have different categories.)

Example of querying 1 product for all its variants (In one query):

```
SELECT
    p.productID,
    p.name,
    p.longDescription,
    p.shortDescription,
    colors.color,
    sizes.size,
    pvar.quantity,
    pprice.price,
    images.imageFilename
FROM products as p
JOIN product_variants as pvar
     ON p.productID = pvar.productID
JOIN productpricing as pprice
    ON pprice.productID = p.productID
JOIN colors 
    ON colors.colorID = pvar.colorID
JOIN sizes
    ON sizes.sizeID = pvar.sizeID
JOIN product_variant_images as pvari
    ON pvari.productvariantID = pvar.productvariantID
JOIN images 
    ON images.imageID = pvari.imageID
WHERE p.productID = 1 AND pvar.isActive = 1 AND NOW() BETWEEN pprice.startDate AND pprice.endDate;
```

Example return set:

```
# productID, name, longDescription, shortDescription, color, size, quantity, price, imageFilename
'1', 'A shirt', 'Long description of this product', 'shortDesc of shirt', 'White', '50', '2', '309.99', 'shirtwhite1.jpg'
'1', 'A shirt', 'Long description of this product', 'shortDesc of shirt', 'White', '50', '2', '309.99', 'shirtwhite2.jpg'
'1', 'A shirt', 'Long description of this product', 'shortDesc of shirt', 'White', '56', '5', '309.99', 'shirtwhite1.jpg'
'1', 'A shirt', 'Long description of this product', 'shortDesc of shirt', 'White', '56', '5', '309.99', 'shirtwhite2.jpg'
'1', 'A shirt', 'Long description of this product', 'shortDesc of shirt', 'Blue', '56', '1', '309.99', 'shirtblue1.jpg'
'1', 'A shirt', 'Long description of this product', 'shortDesc of shirt', 'Blue', '56', '1', '309.99', 'shirtblue2.jpg'
```

As can be seen in the result set the white variant (of one size) of the shirt is associated with two images, therefore there are two records with only *imageFilename* containing "new data".

Example of using several queries:

```
SELECT 
    p.productID,
    p.name,
    p.longDescription,
    p.shortDescription,
    pprice.price
FROM products as p
JOIN productpricing as pprice
    ON pprice.productID = p.productID
WHERE p.productID = 1 AND NOW() BETWEEN pprice.startDate AND pprice.endDate;

SELECT
    c.color,
    s.size,
    pvar.quantity
FROM product_variants as pvar
JOIN colors AS c
    ON c.colorID = pvar.colorID
JOIN sizes as s
    ON s.sizeID = pvar.sizeID
WHERE pvar.productID = 1;

SELECT DISTINCT
    c.color,
    i.imageFilename
FROM images  AS i
JOIN product_variant_images as pvari
    ON pvari.imageID = i.imageID
JOIN product_variants as pvar
    ON pvar.productvariantID = pvari.productvariantID
JOIN colors AS c
    ON c.colorID = pvar.colorID
WHERE pvar.productID = 1;
```

Several queries result sets:

```
# productID, name, longDescription, shortDescription, price
'1', 'A shirt', 'Long description of this product', 'shortDesc of shirt', '309.99'

# color, size, quantity
'White', '50', '2'
'Blue', '56', '1'
'White', '56', '5'

# color, imageFilename
'White', 'shirtwhite1.jpg'
'White', 'shirtwhite2.jpg'
'Blue', 'shirtblue1.jpg'
'Blue', 'shirtblue2.jpg'
```

**Any advice regarding the database design/queries is much appreciated!**

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. Currently your question is missing the test data (data samples) for each table. Could you [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/216764/edit) that in to your question?

Comment: I've updated the post with the test data.

Comment: Hi. Please explain what are you trying to do that is the reason why you are querying. Display certain things to a user? You give a join query result but ask whether you should return some join inputs instead. How can we know? Generally we query 1:1 with the underlying relation(ship) that we are displaying to the user & there is no reason to return otherwise duplicate data & in general you can't reconstruct the arguments of a join anyway. Generally we query relation(ship) data (DBMS) then format via non-relational operators (GUI). There will be processing reasonably done in either domain.

Comment: (This Question looks like a duplicate; didn't you ask it somewhere else?)